# Android, spinner item disappeared after clicking on other spinner

Tags: java, android, android-studio, fragment, spinner

Scenario: Let's say there are 2 spinner in the fragment called spinner `a` and `b`:

> Spinner `a` contain: dog cat elephant
>
> Spinner `b` contain: micky, minny, moe

My question is: Is it possible that when user using apps, and clicked Spinner `a`, and choose `elephant`, the `micky` and `minny` option in Spinner `b` option be gone and only leaving `moe` as an option?

And what is the best way to do it? (not using any database)

xml:

```
<Spinner 
android:id="@+id/spinner_a"
android:entries="@array/value_a"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>

<Spinner 
android:id="@+id/spinner_b"
android:entries="@array/value_b"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

string value:

```
<resources>
<string-array name="value_a">
    <item>dog</item>
    <item>cat</item>
    <item>Elephant</item>
    </string-array>
<string-array name="value_b">
    <item>micky</item>
    <item>minny</item>
    <item>moe</item>
</string-array>
```

java:

```
package...
import....
public class testing123 extends Fragment{

    final Spinner a123 = (Spinner) getView().findViewById(R.id.spinner_a);
    final Spinner b123 = (Spinner) getView().findViewById(R.id.spinner_b);

    final String ax = a123.getSelectedItem().toString();
    final String bx = b123.getSelectedItem().toString();

    if (ax.equals("elephant")) { 
     //what is the best way to do it?
    }else{}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can but not with your way. 
For spinner a it's ok, but for b you should manage it dinamically from Java code.
Add to spinner A a listener and modify string-array of spinner b based on item a selected.

Listener:

```
Spinner spinner_a = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_a);
spinner_a.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // retrieve selected item
                String spinner_a_choice = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                // elaborate and set here your spinner b with its own adapter
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // Something else
            }
        });
```

How to add an adapter to spinner (you have to manipulate it):

```
Spinner spinner_b = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_b);

ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.value_b, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

spinner_b.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: sorry i am not really good, since i am using fragment, with what should i change the "this" in the ArrayAdapter<CharSeq.................   ??

Comment: `getActivity().getApplicationContext();` but care because it will return null if the fragment has been detached

Comment: tried your advice, got null pointer exception error, here the logcat : [link] (http://textuploader.com/5oknv)

Comment: This is because your fragment has been detached. I'm sorry but i don't know how to help you for this problema. I never worked without activity. If you find a solution for this, my code will solve your problem